# awk bring same field value from file1 and set in file2

Tags: awk, search, replace

File1 (parent)

```
2210 1110 Earth
2211 1111 Marse
2212 1112 Saturn
2213 1113 Pluto
```

File2  (child)

```
3310 2210 Earth
3311 2210 Space
3312 2211 Mars
3313 2211 Space
3314 2212 Saturn
3315 2212 Space
3316 2213 Pluto
3317 2213 Space
```

DESIRED

```
3310 2210 Earth
3311 2210 Earth
3312 2211 Mars
3313 2211 Mars
3314 2212 Saturn
3315 2212 Saturn
3316 2213 Pluto
3317 2213 Pluto
```

so it should compare $2 of file2 with $1 of file1, then set value of $3 in file2 same as $3 from file2

Comment: Your post does not contain a question. I assume you want someone to write the code for you. What have you tried? What search results did you find that did not help?

Comment: In your output, why is `3313 2211` Earth? Shouldn't it be Marse? Similarly, shouldn't `3317 2213` be Pluto?

Comment: yes @glennjackman , I'll edit output

Comment: Now the output seems ok. This task is certainly duplicated across the UL, with minor modifications.

Comment: What if a $2 of file2 doesn't exist as a $1 of file1?

Comment: @EdMorton it does Ed!. but if so let's assume we'll not print those lines

Comment: If it does then the accepted answer does what you want. If it might not then the accepted answer doesn't do what you want and you should ask a new question to include such cases if you need help with that.

Comment: ok @EdMorton I posted sample data here to simplify it. In actual, $3 in file2 has similar data as in $1 in file1. and the column I need to bring is $30 from file1 based on that comparison. So I tried ```awk 'FNR==NR {planet[$1]=$30; next} {$30=planet[$2]; print}' file1 file2``` but it's brining empty field

Comment: If your original question didn't cover all your requirements and you need more help then just ask a new question. If the answer you accepted doesn't do what you want then its not clear why you accepted it but you could comment under it to ask a question of the person who provided it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {planet[$1]=$3; next} {$3=planet[$2]; print}' file1 file2
3310 2210 Earth
3311 2210 Earth
3312 2211 Marse
3313 2211 Marse
3314 2212 Saturn
3315 2212 Saturn
3316 2213 Pluto
3317 2213 Pluto
```

- `FNR==NR` is an `awk` idiom meaning "when parsing the first file". It's necessary to end the action of this condition with `next` to avoid running the remaining code for the first file.
- The planet field is stored into a hash array and during reading the second file, we assign it to the last field.

Comment: I posted sample data here to simplify it. In actual, $3 in file2 has similar data as in $1 in file1. and the column I need to bring is $30 from file1 based on that comparison. So I tried awk 'FNR==NR {planet[$1]=$30; next} {$30=planet[$2]; print}' file1 file2 but it's brining empty field

Comment: OK, then you will get `$30` from file1, with `planet[$1]=$30`. That's about file1. Now about file2, what is the target column you want to overwrite? If it is X, and "column $3 of file2 is mapped to column $1 of file1", then you will use `$X=planet[$3]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are both sorted lexicographically on the join field (the 1st field in `file1` and the 2nd field in `file2`):

```bsh
$ join -1 1 -2 2 -o 2.1,2.2,1.3 file1 file2
3310 2210 Earth
3311 2210 Earth
3312 2211 Marse
3313 2211 Marse
3314 2212 Saturn
3315 2212 Saturn
3316 2213 Pluto
3317 2213 Pluto
```

This performs a relational JOIN operation between the two files, using the 1st field of the first file and the 2nd field of the second file (`-1 1 -2 2`).  The output is specified using the `-o` option, and in the command above, `2.1,2.2,1.3` gives us the 1st and 2nd fields from the second file, followed by the 3rd field from the first file.